# What should I use to make this kind of cell, so I can get each of them to segue to different ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

Here is what I want to do (UI is showing down below), I want to perform different segue when I taped different cell in it. But I don't know what component I should use to get this done

I think to use the Collection View Controller, but it seems doest support static cells,  I want to use Customized UIVIew to do this, but it couldn't be dragged to another VC in StoryBoard, should I adopt some sort of Protocols of something to do this?

Please answer in Swift

[image: UI Page]

---

### After been helped

> Turns out I just need to show the ViewController and haven't need segue yet, so here is the code.

```
let categories: [(name: String, pic: String, identifier: String)] = [
    ("人物",  "Wilson_head",      "CharactersVC"),
    ("动物",  "Pig",              "MobsVC"),
    ("植物",  "Bamboo_Patch",     "PlantsVC"),
    ("食谱",  "Crock_Pot_Build",  "RecipesVC")
]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
    let destVC: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: currentCategory.identifier)
    navigationController!.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: with Collection View Controller its possible.

Comment: Try using collection view delegate method `didSelectItemAt indexPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            let objstory = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “your Story bord identifier”) as! Your View_ViewController


            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objstory, animated: true)
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection View Controller doesn't support static cell.
But you can add static cell programmatically.

1. set your cell data and target(segue id) for each cell.
   ex:

   `cellData[0].segue = "segueToHuman"`

   `cellData[1].segue = "segueToAnimal"`
2. add segues depend on your view controller(not on cell) like below:

[create segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op7R6.png)

[image]

[segue setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9lDg.png)

[image]

3. perform particular segue in `didSelectItemAt indexPath`

   `let segueID = cellData[indexPath.row].segue
   performSegue(withIdentifier: segueID, sender: nil)`